# programatically install headers and dependent headers using scons

Tags: header, dependencies, installation, scons

I'm using scons as my build system and I'd like to install my project's development headers using scons as well. I'd like to avoid maintaining a list of all the needed headers and their include dependencies and instead use the built-in dependency parsing magic of scons to provide this list for me.

As an example I have 2 headers I want to install, explicitly, Foo1.h and Foo2.h:

```
/* Foo1.h */
#ifndef FOO1_H_
#define FOO1_H_

#include "Bar.h"
#include <somelibrary.h>

/* header contents */

#endif /* FOO1_H_ */
```

and

```
/* Foo2.h */
#ifndef FOO2_H_
#define FOO2_H_

/* header contents */

#endif /* FOO2_H_ */
```

Since Bar.h is required by Foo1.h, I want it to be installed too, automagically. somelibrary.h shouldn't be part of the installed headers. There has to be some way to accomplish this *or* there has to be some reason what I'm trying to do isn't advisable.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured out the answer. Here's the code snippet that'll do exactly what I was talking about:

```
def getDependentIncludes(environ, explicit_includes, search_path, depincludes):
    for inc in explicit_includes:
        if inc not in depincludes:
            depincludes.add(inc)
            incs = SCons.Defaults.CScan(inc, environ, search_path)
            getDependentIncludes(environ, incs, search_path, depincludes)
# create a set of all the headers
development_headers = set()
# call function, with development_headers storing the result
getDependentIncludes(env, 
                 external_facing_headers, 
                 include_dirs, development_headers)
# print the glorious results
names = map(lambda x : '"./' + os.path.relpath(str(x), Dir("#").abspath) + '"', development_headers)
names.sort()
print " ".join(names)
```